# Delphi - identcache extension

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/File_Extensions_of_Files_Generated_by_RAD_Studio), this extension is used for refactoring. Is any possibility to physically exclude this files?

Comment: It appears to be auto-generated. I just ignore it (and set up SVN to ignore that extension as well). It usually doesn't bother anything, unless it somehow gets out of synch, and then I just delete it and let the IDE rebuild it when it needs it.

Comment: Physically exclude the file *from what*? Also, "physically" is a strange word to apply to a non-physical thing.

Comment: I ignore these files all the time as well, and perhaps this link will help you understand things more: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions

Comment: Besides ignoring them in your version control system (svn ignore, hg ignore, or whatetever), my "clean.cmd" deletes them, along with *.dcu and *.local, so that obscure build and IDE issues are resolved thereby.  But no you can't stop the IDE from creating them.

Comment: @Warren surely you create a brand new working copy each time you do a release build?

Comment: A brand new working copy? Not necessary with mercurial.

Comment: I guess you are talking about excluding the file from your repository system, otherwise it is not really possible to *physically* exclude a file unless you cut parts of your HDD :)